# How do I detect the url of where the user is coming from in Javascript/Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, location, browser-detection

I want to detect the origin url of an user entering my website (such to perform certain operations later). Can this be achieved using angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for referrer?

```
var x = document.referrer;
```

Comment: Should work in JavaScript and angular with no problems. The only catch is that this is essentially the location the user would go if they hit the back button so after they click on a link on your site it'll update.

Comment: Yeag but that can be solved again by only registering it at first visit